# How to Normalize similarity measures from Wordnet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, similarity, wordnet

I am trying to calculate semantic similarity between two words. I am using Wordnet-based similarity measures i.e Resnik measure(RES), Lin measure(LIN), Jiang and Conrath measure(JNC) and Banerjee and Pederson measure(BNP).

To do that, I am using nltk and Wordnet 3.0. Next, I want to combine the similarity values obtained from different measure. To do that i need to normalize the similarity values as some measure give values between 0 and 1, while others give values greater than 1.

So, my question is how do I normalize the similarity values obtained from different measures.

**Extra detail** on what I am actually trying to do: I have a set of words. I calculate pairwise similarity between the words. and remove the words that are not strongly correlated with other words in the set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### How to normalize a single measure

Let's consider a single arbitrary similarity measure `M` and take an arbitrary word `w`.

Define `m = M(w,w)`. Then m takes maximum possible value of `M`.

Let's define `MN` as a normalized measure `M`.

For any two words `w, u` you can compute `MN(w, u) = M(w, u) / m`.

It's easy to see that if `M` takes non-negative values, then `MN` takes values in `[0, 1]`.

### How to normalize a measure combined from many measures

In order to compute your own defined measure `F` combined of k different measures `m_1, m_2, ..., m_k` first normalize independently each `m_i` using above method and then define:

```
alpha_1, alpha_2, ..., alpha_k
```

such that `alpha_i` denotes the weight of i-th measure.

All alphas must sum up to 1, i.e:

```
alpha_1 + alpha_2 + ... + alpha_k = 1
```

Then to compute your own measure for `w, u` you do:

```
F(w, u) = alpha_1 * m_1(w, u) + alpha_2 * m_2(w, u) + ... + alpha_k * m_k(w, u)
```

It's clear that `F` takes values in [0,1]

Comment: You need a minimum reputation of 15 to do that it seems. I have only 5 :). I have "accepted" the asnwer though

Comment: What if `M(w,w)` = 0?

Comment: @JustB any reasonable model assigns `M(w, w)` a positive value, because `w` is the most similar word to `w`.

Comment: @pkacprzak I used nltk and it's similarity methods but in some methods like jcn_similarity it returns inf ( its1e300 in the case of nltk) and for some methods M(w,w) for different methods are not even equal! for example if w is 'escape.n.01' res_similarity(w,w) is 8.4 and if w is 'car.n.01' res_similarity(w,w) is 7.5 for some method like jcn_sim result is inf what should i do? what is the problem?

Comment: @MiladM the exact value may depend on the actual measure. I suggest to take a look at the documentation of these measures.

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes that's right. After some research I found that the maximum value in some methods depends on P(w) ,the probability of word w in the corpus (like brown corpus). so M(w,w) is not the maximum value in some cases. but there are measures like lch_similarity that M(w,w) is the maximum value or in some cases the maximum value is 1 (lin and wup measures) so for other cases I think we should find all possible values in our corpus. maybe you can update your answer ;)

Comment: @MiladM I think that for a given w, M(w, w) is still maximum for set {M(w, s) | s is a word in the language} regardless of its exact value.

Comment: How to define `alpha_i`? Is it personal choice or any formula?

Comment: @Shokatsuryō the value of `alpha_i` can be interpreted as its weight, and greater weight means more important the measure related to this weight is. For example, if you have 2 different measures and you think that they both are equally important, you can assign them weights 0.5 and 0.5. On the other hand, if you think that one measure is more important than the other, just assign it a greater value. I've been using this approach successfully. Is it more clear right now?

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you for the explanation @pkacprzak. One last question, is there any resources or papers where your normalize measurement comes from? I am just curious. If there isn't, it's OK.

Comment: @Shokatsuryō I came up with this on my own, but I think that this method is so simple and straightforward that it's widely used. You can always google for it and figure it out :) Such a weighting approach is not only connected to NLP, but just a general method for combining two or more functions into a single one and taking advantage of the knowledge about how much each function is "important"