# How to normalize similarity measurements (lch, wup, path, res, lin, jcn) between [0,1]?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to calculate semantic similarity between two words. I am using Wordnet-based similarity measures i.e Resnik measure(RES), Lin measure(LIN), Jiang, Conrath measure(JNC), and (LCH),  but the similarity value is not between [0-1], So i need to normalize the similarity values as some measure give values between 0 and 1, while others give values greater than 1. even the word is similar or different.

Code example:

> > > from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
> > >
> > > from nltk.corpus import wordnet_ic
> > >
> > > brown_ic = wordnet_ic.ic('ic-brown.dat')
> > >
> > > s1 = wordnet.synsets("car")
> > >
> > > s2 = wordnet.synsets("car")
> > >
> > > wn.wup_similarity(s1[0], s2[0])
> > >
> > > 1.0
> > >
> > > wn.lch_similarity(s1[0], s2[0])
> > >
> > > 3.6375861597263857
> > >
> > > wn.path_similarity(s1[0], s2[0])
> > >
> > > 1.0
> > >
> > > wn.jcn_similarity(s1[0], s2[0], brown_ic)
> > >
> > > 1e+300
> > >
> > > wn.res_similarity(s1[0], s2[0], brown_ic)
> > >
> > > 7.591401417609093
> > >
> > > wn.lin_similarity(s1[0], s2[0], brown_ic)
> > >
> > > 1.0

Comment: Annotate a whole corpus with the measure and put the vector through a sigmoid function. That would usually work.

Comment: I saw the same question in the link  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969532/how-to-normalize-similarity-measures-from-wordnet**.  but  I couldn't apply in my code, please if you could to applying on my example I would be thankful.
 I don't know what is ( words w, u) and what the difference between it and M(w,w). 
If I assume that  M(w,w) is (wn.res_similarity(s1[0], s2[0], brown_ic)),  then what is MN (w, u) really I couldn't understand.